# Error while retrieving data

Tags: android-studio, in-app-purchase

I had an app that was working fine with inapp purchase - I still was in test mode but it was fine. 
Then I decided to go to production but got issues - in the meantime nI had lost my certificate keys, so I had to use another package name, upload a new app on Google play and use new certificate credentials.
Anyway. 
I did the exact same thing with this new app, and I also add the inapp purchase package, but when I launch the app I have this error :

Error while retrieving the informations from the server ([DF-AA-20])

Any idea of why I have this error message ?
I checked the inapp package name several times and it's ok...
What could be the issue ?

I've been trying to solve this for hours...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by doing these steps:
- I copied the public key found in "Services & API" google account and added it in my code
- I published the app in alpha mode and had to wait until it was really "published", and not "pending publishing"
Now it's working fine and I'm able to make test purchases. 
But then I deleted the test account and tried to make a real purchase, and I'm having this error:
"Error: Impossible to buy this article"

Does anybody had this issue ?

Thanks